# pygame Surface from RGB565

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame and I'm trying to create a Surface from an RGB565 buffer, this is what I have so far:

```
def rgb_to_surface(buff):
    arr = np.fromstring(buff, dtype=np.uint16).newbyteorder('S')
    r = (((arr & 0xF800) >>11)*255.0/31.0).astype(np.uint8)
    g = (((arr & 0x07E0) >>5) *255.0/63.0).astype(np.uint8)
    b = (((arr & 0x001F) >>0) *255.0/31.0).astype(np.uint8)
    arr = np.concatenate((r,g,b))
    return pygame.image.frombuffer(arr, (160, 120), 'RGB')
```

It works, except that the image is tiled, any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have used `column_stack` to get `r g b r g b...`

```
arr = np.column_stack((r,g,b)).flat[0:]
```